# use session variables as parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have to following parameters that are necessary to execute a stored procedure in sql server 2008 r2

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", sessionStartDate.ToString());
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", sessionEndDate.ToString());
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentType", payment.ToString());
```

These are necessary to execute a stored procedure. All of the session variables are passed correctly. However when the gridview renders it shows no data. I know there is data because I can run the stored procedure on SSMS and it runs perfectly with the parameters that are passing to the proc (when I input them).

I am pretty confused at this point so any help would be helpful.

```
grdDenialDetail.DataSource = ds.Tables["DetailDenial"].DefaultView;
grdDenialDetail.DataBind();
```

ENTIRE ROUTINE:  (maybe this will help)

```
public void ExecuteDetailReport()
{
    string sessionConnection = Session["Company"].ToString();
    string sessionStartDate = Session["StartDate"].ToString();
    string sessionEndDate = Session["EndDate"].ToString();
    string payment = Session["payment"].ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[sessionConnection].ConnectionString);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.cusGenDenialReportPivotStylePType", conn);

    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    /*da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11)).Value = sessionStartDate.ToString();
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11)).Value = sessionEndDate.ToString();
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PaymentType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = payment.ToString();*/
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", sessionStartDate);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", sessionEndDate);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentType", payment);
    lblTest.Visible = true;
    lblTest.Text = "You selected " + payment + ".";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds, "DetailDenial");

    grdDenialDetail.DataSource = ds.Tables["DetailDenial"].DefaultView;
    grdDenialDetail.DataBind();

    da.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where's your binding code?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: There's no need to `ToString()` each of the variables; the type of second parameter to `AddWithValue` is `object`. If you leave it on, you may end up passing the variables to SQL server in a format it doesn't understand.

Comment: curious I removed the     .ToString    and it still produced no data

Comment: I added the entire routine to see if that would help

Comment: Where do you *set* the session variables? There's no need to make the variables all strings if that's not their true data type. I would leave them their native types and let .NET and ADO.NET do all the conversion for you.

Comment: @Cory: So when I set the session I would do it like this [code] Session["StartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text [\code] and then I would call them like this [code] sessionStartDate = Session["StartDate"] [/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is related to the fact that you are using and comparing dates as strings and not dates. Your result set is empty because your query is trying to compare date strings *alphabetically* instead of *chronologically*. To refactor your code, I would make sure that you address the following areas:

**Setting the session variables**

Carefully parse the dates out of your text fields.

```
DateTime startDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
{
    Session["StartDate"] = startDate;
}

DateTime endDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out endDate))
{
    Session["EndDate"] = endDate;
}
```

You may want to handle the case when the `TryParseExact` methods return `false` (parse failure).

**Retrieving session variables**

We set the session variables as `DateTime` objects, so cast them back upon retrieval:

```
var sessionStartDate = (DateTime)Session["StartDate"];
var sessionEndDate = (DateTime)Session["EndDate"];
```

Notice we're still using native .NET types here.

**Setting up your query parameters**

Use the `.Date` property of the `DateTime` struct to drop the time component:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", sessionStartDate.Date);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", sessionEndDate.Date);
...
```

And lastly, update your stored procedure so that its parameters are of type `date`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.cusGenDenialReportPivotStylePType
(
    @StartDate date = null,
    @EndDate date = null,
    ...
)
AS
...
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Somewhere
    WHERE
        TheDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Keeping everything in its native data format will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you Cory!  My only other issue is an error now which is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and it highlights the line "var sessionStartDate = (DateTime)Session["StartDate"] "  The variable appears to be passing to the session but not to the sproc.  I did change the sproc to have startdate and enddate in the DATE data type as you demonstrated above

Comment: As I stepped through the code it is not picking up the start date but is picking up the end date.  I will examine that further

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.ToString()` calls from your code.

Comment: Igor I did this and it still produced no data

Comment: This was the obvious thing wrong in your code. I don't know the types of variables `sessionStartDate`, `sessionEndDate` and `payment`, how `da.SelectCommand` is set up, what types of parameters your stored procedure expects.

Comment: All of the session... variables are string values and the stored procedure expects VARCHAR values.  VARCHAR and string are the same correct?

Comment: how were the string values for `sessionStartDate`, `sessionEndDate` and `payment` assigned? What is stored procedure doing with them?

Comment: I actually passed the session variables to string variables at the beginning of the routine.  The stored procedure uses them in the where clause to eliminate records

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question-  sessionStartDate and sessionEndDate are derived from textboxes.  payment is taken from a click procedure on another datagrid

Comment: This is what I have guessed. How were the values that are stored in `Session` obtained? What are the fields (and their types) that you compare the parameters with in the stored procedure?

Comment: The sessionStartDate is compared to @StartDate in sql and that is a DATETIME field converted to VARCHAR(11) to drop the time portion.  sessionEndDate is the exact same.  payment is compared to "@PaymentType" which is a VARCHAR(200) in sql.  Did I answer your question?

Comment: @MaximusPrime: what format are your `varchar(11)` dates in? Are they in a sortable format? Remember, as strings, your dates would be getting sorted alphabetically, not chronologically.

Comment: @Cory:  The dates are in the following format (mm/dd/yyyy) but can be input like this for example 1/1/1900

Comment: You should be comparing dates as dates. Doing comparison of dates converted to strings is a sad and frustrating endeavor - as you are discovering.

Comment: I agree but it was the only way I know to drop the time portion of the field and just keep the date.  So I think I am stuck trying to do it this way unfortunately

Comment: You realize, of course, that, as a string, "9/1/1900" is greater than "11/1/1900"

Comment: I realize that and that is more than likely the issue.  What would you suggest?  I tried to run the stored procedure with date and it will not accept the input of "1/1/1900" and if I use datetime it expects a time.    Can you convert it in C#?

Comment: @MaximusPrime: `new DateTime(1, 1, 1900, ...).Date` will drop the time portion. Your stored procedure parameters should have the `date` type, not `datetime`. ADO.NET will handle the rest.